# Receiving Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at String.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I built a form that checks for filled or empty input values, and then it adds progress to the circle. As it stands, I'm getting a call stack error due to the amount of calls that the functions receive. The library that I'm using for the circle-progress bar is called JQuery-Circle-Progress. How can I re-write my function(s) to avoid getting a callstack error while checking for input values?

I tried to combine the functions that check for empty and nil strings, but they stopped working after I made the changes, and the error is still occurring. **The answers that are posted on stackoverflow for similar questions, didn't address the fact that I am working with many inputs with different ids. I cannot use the array method, since all of the ids are for unique attributes.** Otherwise, I would iterate over one array of inputs and easily pickup the changes in value. In the documentation for this jquery-library, I don't see how you can add progress to the progress circle without redrawing it.

```
let test_form_progress_value = 0;
$('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({
    animation: {duration: 2000},
    fill: {color: '#fdba04'},
    value: 0.0,
    size: 150,
    startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
    animationStartValue: 0,
    stepValue: test_form_progress_value
}).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress) {

    $('#test_form_id').bind('blur', function () {
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({value: test_form_progress_value += 0.001});
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress('redraw');
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress();
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({size: 150});
    });

    $('#test_form_id').bind('blur', function () {
        if ($('#test_form_id').val() == '') {
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({value: test_form_progress_value -= 0.001});
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress('redraw');
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress();
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({size: 150});
        }
    });

    $('#test_form_username').bind('blur', function () {
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({value: test_form_progress_value += 0.001});
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress('redraw');
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress();
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({size: 150});
    });

    $('#test_form_username').bind('blur', function () {
        if ($('#test_form_username').val() == '') {
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({value: test_form_progress_value -= 0.001});
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress('redraw');
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress();
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({size: 150});
        }
    });

    $('#test_form_password').bind('blur', function () {
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({value: test_form_progress_value += 0.001});
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress('redraw');
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress();
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({size: 150});
    });

    $('#test_form_password').bind('blur', function () {
        if ($('#test_form_password').val() == '') {
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({value: test_form_progress_value -= 0.001});
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress('redraw');
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress();
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({size: 150});
        }
    });


    $('#test_form_movie_review').bind('blur', function () {
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({value: test_form_progress_value += 0.001});
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress('redraw');
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress();
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({size: 150});
    });

    $('#test_form_movie_name').bind('blur', function () {
        if ($('#test_form_movie_name').val() == '') {
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({value: test_form_progress_value -= 0.001});
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress('redraw');
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress();
            $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({size: 150});
        }
    });

    $(this).find('strong').html(Math.ceil((test_form_progress_value * 83)) + '<i>%</i>');
});

$('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({
    fill: {color: '#fdba04'},
    value: 0.0,
    size: 150,
    startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
    animationStartValue: 0,
    stepValue: test_form_progress_value
}).on('circle-animation-end', function (event) {

    if ($('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress('value') === 0) {
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({value: 0});
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress('redraw');
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress();
        $('.test-progress.circle-2').circleProgress({size: 150});
    }
});
```

Expected results: I should see the progression bar moving without any Maximum call stack size exceeded errors.

Actual results: The progression bar moves, but fails midway, due to the callstack error.